# Characterization of the hypergeometric function

Tags: cv.complex-variables, hypergeometric-functions, monodromy

One of the definition of the hypergeometric function $_2 F_1$ rely only on its global properties around the singularities (and not on a differential equation or a serie expansion)

In modern language (and here I'm just copy pasting from [PlanetMath](http://planetmath.org/globalcharacterizationofhypergeometricfunction)):

> Suppose that we have a sheaf of holomorphic functions over $\mathbb{C} 
> \setminus \{0,1\}$ which satisfy the following properties:
>
> - It is closed under analytic continuation.
> - It is closed under taking linear combinations.
> - The space of function elements over any open set is two dimensional.
> - There exists a neighborhood $D_0$ such that $0 \in D_0$, holomorphic 
>     functions $\phi_0, \psi_0$ defined on $D_0$, and complex numbers $\alpha_0,\beta_0$ such that, for an open set of $D_0$ not containing $0$, it happens that  $z \mapsto z^{\alpha_0} \phi(z)$ and $z \mapsto z^{\beta_0} \psi(z)$ belong to our sheaf.
>
> Then the sheaf consists of solutions to a hypergeometric equation

This characterization seems to have been made by Riemann (at least [Deligne and Mostow](https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/Number48.pdf) attribute it to him (p. 2)).
But I cannot find any modern reference/proof for this fact, except for [the original paper by Riemann](https://www.emis.de/classics/Riemann/PFunct.pdf) (and I don't speak German).

It looks like common knowledge and I'm probably missing a keyword, or a well known reference. Any help is appreciated.

> I'm looking for a proof of this result, and I'm also interested by any generalization of this theorem when the space of function elements is more than two dimensional.

Comment: L. Ahlfors, Complex Analysis, Chapter 8, section 4.