# Does the Riemann characterization of the hypergeometric function have a q-analog?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables, special-functions, hypergeometric-functions, q-analogs

This question is inspired by another recent one here, [Characterization of the hypergeometric function](https://mathoverflow.net/q/280794/41291). The latter is about the classical result of Riemann characterizing the hypergeometric functions as sections of any two-dimensional subsheaf of the sheaf of functions analytic away from $\{0,1\}$ and having local expansions of the form $z^{\alpha_0}f_0(z)$ near zero and $(1-z)^{\alpha_1}f_1(z)$ near 1 with $f_i$ holomorphic at $i$. The additional condition is closure under analytic continuation which I don't really understand how to formulate in purely sheaf-theoretic terms (probably some pushforwards must be involved but I do not see any details). I also suspect one should say something about behavior at $\infty$ but again, I am not sure. In any case, the question cites a paper by Deligne-Mostow, as well as the original paper of Riemann, while in a comment [Alexandre Eremenko](https://mathoverflow.net/users/25510/alexandre-eremenko) refers to the very last entry in the "Complex Analysis" by Ahlfors for a detailed treatment.

My question is whether a similar characterization of the [basic hypergeometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_hypergeometric_series) is known. I mean their characterizations in terms of some sheaf of functions with prescribed singularities at given points, or finite amount of similar kind of local data, without mentioning any $q$-difference equations or any explicit series expansions.

I tried to look in Gasper & Rahman, Fine, Bailey, Slater, as well as Kac-Cheung and Etingof-Frenkel-Kirillov. I might well overlook it but the fact is I could not find anything.

Comment: This survey paper [Isomonodromy for complex linear q-difference equations](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiLuLPdiLHXAhWGJ1AKHbXBCr8QFggrMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.emis.de%2Fjournals%2FSC%2F2006%2F14%2Fpdf%2Fsmf_sem-cong_14_249-280.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1GTkdbP6UeFt9Ys4zyjmLx) gives classification of linear q-difference equations using connection matrix. They give geometric interpretation of the connection matrix in section 1.3. They also refer to sheafs throughout their paper several times.

Comment: @Nemo Many thanks for the link, this is certainly highly relevant and contains lots of further references. Will try to find what I need...